# I am using Amazon connect and I am trying to transfer my phone number dynamically . But I am getting the error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-connect

I have my flow settings as follows :
Transfer: dynamic ,
Name Space : User defined and
Key : ReminderText .
But i am unable to make a call using this .

When I select as transfer as manually instead of dynamic and set ReminderText as some phone number :''99223-0-992'  , I am able to make a call .The issues arises in case of dynamic transfer .

I am  providing the snippet of my lambda code .

```
connect_client = boto3.client('connect')

print(f"dst :{event['dst']}")
print(f"customer :{event['customer']}")

try:
    
    response = connect_client.start_outbound_voice_contact(
      
        DestinationPhoneNumber='+91'+event['dst'],
        InstanceId='---------------',
   
        ContactFlowId='-------------',
        SourcePhoneNumber='+815034553029',

        Attributes={
         'ReminderText':event['customer']
        }
    )
```

I am getting the below mentioned error when i set transfer to dynamic .

Error : Failed Error: An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartOutboundVoiceContact operation: Request contains attribute keys that are not valid

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see you Connect config, I suspect the issue is the number used in `SourcePhoneNumber` is not a phone number claimed in your connect instance.

This is a requirement when making outbound calls to stop phone number spoofing.